# IS_ROLEMEMBER erroneously returns 0 for database role members?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Running a local instance of `SQL Server 2012`.

I have created a custom role:

```
CREATE ROLE [my_user] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
```

For all my users (local Windows users and SQL users), I have specified this role for my database (under the `User Mappings` setting). Thus, the following query should return 1:

```
SELECT IS_ROLEMEMBER('my_user')
```

For my Windows-authenticated users it does indeed return 1, but as soon as I'm logged on as an **SQL user**, it **returns 0**. I have triple-checked that the SQL user does indeed have this role. What am I missing here?

### Update

Performed some more testing. This certainly is weird behavior. I performed these steps:

1. On my local `SQL Server` I created a database `test` with user `sa`. Role `my_user` added.
2. Logged on as `sa` in the `Management Studio` and added `MYDOMAIN\MyUser` to this role.
3. Re-logged on with Windows Authentication and executed `IS_ROLEMEMBER('my_user')`. **Returns 0.**
4. Tried the query using both `sa` (specifying the username) and the Windows user. Same problem.
5. Tried restarting the `SQL Server`, just in case.

**This makes no sense!** If I right-click the role I can see that my Windows user is indeed a member of it. The `IS_ROLEMEMBER` function is flawed! When I run the following query, it shows that my user is indeed a member of the database role:

```
SELECT
    USER_NAME(memberuid), USER_NAME(groupuid)
FROM
    sys.sysmembers
WHERE
    USER_NAME(groupuid) = 'my_user'
```

This also shows my membership:

```
select r.name as role_name, m.name as member_name from sys.database_role_members rm 
inner join sys.database_principals r on rm.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
inner join sys.database_principals m on rm.member_principal_id = m.principal_id
```

Some additional information:

- I'm on a domain, but currently disconnected. I have seen this problem when connected too though.
- Running Windows 8.1 64-bit.

### Update 2

If I explicitly specify the principal as some have suggested, I get this error (executing as `sa`):

```
SELECT IS_ROLEMEMBER('my_user', 'MYDOMAIN\UserX')

Msg 15404, Level 16, State 19, Line 1
Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'MYDOMAIN\UserX',
error code 0x54b.
```

Could it be that `IS_ROLEMEMBER` experiences the same problem, but does not print the error?

Comment: What about `IS_MEMBER()`?

Comment: Tried that. Same result.

Comment: does it really return 0 or NULL?

Comment: Is it possible the server login is also the name of a Windows user group ? Also, what results when SELECT IS_ROLEMEMBER('my_user', 'username') ?

Comment: Hmm. Now it works. Could it be that the this function returns 0 for the database owner?

Comment: @DeanG, please see my update. Specifying the principal shows another error (root cause?).

Comment: This issue reproduced for me not only onder database owner. I've noticed that after executing statement EXECUTE AS user = 'UserNameHere' then I can get correct result from IS_ROLEMEMBER('RoleName')

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just had this same issue... I found that the user in question had server roles also assigned to them.  When I removed all server roles except 'public', suddenly the is_rolemember query started correctly reporting a 1 instead of the zero.....  I tested this back and forth a few times to confirm.

Comment: Thanks! This might actually be the root cause!

Comment: I have verified that this is the right answer. A server role, such as 'sysadmin', causes `IS_ROLEMEMBER` to (erroneously?) return 0. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: One of the other answers on this page (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47093146/1786204) covers the "why" (sysadmin presents the user as dbo to the database), so it's not exactly a bug but it is odd.

Answer (score 4):

Also had this issue. Turns out I had to remove sysadmin server role, then it worked.

This is taken from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/is-member-transact-sql

> Members of the sysadmin fixed server role enter every database as the dbo user. Checking permission for member of the sysadmin fixed server role, checks permissions for dbo, not the original login. Since dbo can't be added to a database role and doesn’t exist in Windows groups, dbo will always return 0 (or NULL if the role doesn't exist).

Answer (score 3):

Try specifying the principal explicitly.

```
SELECT IS_ROLEMEMBER('my_user', 'SqlLogin')
```

I tested this and it returned 1.

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDatabase;
GO

USE TestDatabase;
GO

CREATE ROLE TestRole AUTHORIZATION dbo;
GO

CREATE USER TestUser WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'TestRole', 'TestUser';
GO

SELECT IS_ROLEMEMBER('TestRole', 'TestUser');
GO
```

Comment: What happens if `TestUser` is the owner of the database? Does it still return 1 for `TestRole`?

Comment: Still returns 1 when I tested it.

Comment: Is it possible that this is different on SQL Express?

Comment: I don't see why that would be the case.  There's nothing in the documentation that implies this from what I can see.  Did you try running the above script?

Comment: please see my update. I get error code 0x54b when I run your script with my domain user (offline).

Comment: Do you get the error when you run the above code with the test account?  If not, then the problem is likely related to being disconnected from your domain.  Registering a domain account without being able to connect to the domain -- that seems like a recipe for failure.

Comment: It's a bad recipe for sure, but working offline with a local SQL Server is a quite common scenario for a developer. And yes, it works for an SQL test account (which is of course independent of the AD). If you ask me, the documentation for `IS_ROLEMEMBER` should clearly state that it verifies accounts on the AD if applicable.